# Cleaning up after a ruby script -- trapping signals

Tags: ruby, bash, error-handling, signals, bash-trap

My ruby script creates a tempfile and spawns an potentially long-running external process. Neither may continue to exist after the script ends, no matter the way in which the script terminates.

I thought the following lines would take care of things:

```
stderr = File.open(Tempfile.new(__FILE__),'w')
trap("EXIT") { FileUtils.rm_f stderr.path }
pid = spawn("dd", *ARGV, STDERR => stderr )
trap("EXIT") { FileUtils.rm_f stderr.path; Process.kill pid }
```

they're supposed to be a rewrite of the following bash code, which seems to work fine,

```
dd_output=`mktemp`
trap "rm -f $dd_output" EXIT
dd "$@" 2>| $dd_output & pid=$!
trap "rm -f $dd_output; kill $pid" EXIT
```

but they don't. 
If an exception is raised later on, the spawned process doesn't die, otherwise it does.

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Edit:
   Traps do work.
   The above code has multiple blemishes:

1. Tempfile takes car of itself -- it is likely to already have been
   deleted in the trap handler, which may cause FileUtils.rm_f to raise
   another error, preventing.
2. Process.kill needs a signal -- Process.kill "TERM", pid (or "KILL"). The raised error shadowed the error for my faulty invocation of Process.kill.

Fixed code:

```
 stderr = Tempfile.new(__FILE__)
 pid = spawn("dd", *ARGV, STDERR => stderr )
 trap("EXIT") { Process.kill "TERM", pid }
```

`Ensure` works too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think **ensure** might be able to help you here, it will always execute the code inside. It is similary to Java's **finally**.

```
stderr = Tempfile.new(__FILE__)

begin
  pid = spawn("dd", *ARGV, STDERR => stderr )
ensure
  FileUtils.rm_f stderr.path
  Process.kill pid
end
```

If that doesn't do the trick you could try adding an **at_exit** handler.

Comment: `at_exit` is probably the first thing to try here.